# Timeout issue with NetworkManager Service

Tags: 18.04

In Ubuntu 18.04 , the status of the Network-manager is always activating but after 90 Seconds in the console below logs are coming

```
[OK] failed to start Network-manager 
[OK] Starting Network-manager
```

but service status will remain same as below

```
NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (start) since Fri 2023-04-14 14:33:48 +03; 1min 4s ago
     Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
 Main PID: 2941 (NetworkManager)
    Tasks: 4 (limit: 3968)
   CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
           ��├��─2941 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
           ��└��─2954 /sbin/dhclient -d -q -sf /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper -pf /run/dhclient-eth0.pid -lf /var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-4ef1887a-35da-3ebe-97fb-8974d9a01796-eth0.lease -cf
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe it's trying to load an invalid configuration? Did you check that all connection profiles are up to date and valid?

Comment: Thank you, yes, I check the all configuration like network-manager.service and /etc/network/interfaces file both are proper any other file needed to check.